# single reducer for multiple async calls in react ,redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am calling single post request multiple times like below from a component in React js:

```
    Object.keys(data).map(account => {
        const accountRequest = {
            accountNo: account.accountNo,
            id : account.id
        }
        return this.props.requestAccountDetails(accountRequest)
    }

requestAccountDetails is a function written in const mapDispatchToProps in container:

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)  => {
        return {
            requestAccountDetails : (accountDetails)=> {
                dispatch(requestAccountDetailsInformation(accountDetails));
            }
        }
    }
```

requestAcountDetailsInformation is an action written in action creator which calls redux-saga which is called multiple times asynchronously depending on no of accounts. So, if say number of accounts is 5 , post request I am calling is 5 times asynchronously using  redux-saga.

Issue is when my post request gets returned successfully, I am again calling success action which calls reducer and data is supplied to my component.But as the call is made 5 times and it is calling same success function and same reducer.It overwrites previous call result. Example: If my first request returns result, and second request returns result.My first request result is overwritten in reducer.

Can anyone help me how can I maintain result of all 5 requests in single reducer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add result in array rather than overwrite in it.
let say you have state.

```
const state = {
accountDetails =[]
}
```

In reducer in success call you can push new data in accountDetails and update state.

```
  reducer(initialState=state, action)
    switch(action.type){
      ....
    case Authsuccess: return { ...initialState,
                                accountDetails : [ 
                                ...initialState.accounDetails, 
                                 action.payload.accountInfo
                                 ],
                              }
```

Comment: But accountDetails =[] gets initialized to [] on every call

Comment: no we have initialised array once in initialState. On success call we are appending previously store result in accountDetails and new payload data.

Comment: Provide more details if this is not the case, it seems state is getting empty in every success call.